# JavaScript splice() method removes last item of an array, if the first parameter to splice() is -1

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript `splice()` method to remove an element from an array.
The code is like below,

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function myFunction() {
    var index = fruits.indexOf('Kivi');
    fruits.splice(index , 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
```

After calling the function **the last element of the array will get removed**. Why is that ?

Comment: That's just by design. If you set it to -2 it will remove from the first to last element, etc. So what you are trying to do here isn't going to work. Why don't you just stop executing if `index === -1` and return there? What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: because `fruits.indexOf('Kivi') == -1`, and `-1` tells splice() to take one from the end.

Comment: if the index is a negative number it will work from the end of the array

Comment: [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - `As a negative index, begin indicates an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(-2) extracts the last two elements in the sequence.`

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

"Index at which to start changing the array. If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array. *If negative, will begin that many elements from the end.*"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice